# Countable and uncountable set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Which of the following sets of functions are uncountable?
>
> 1. $\{f|f:\Bbb N\to\{1,2\}\}$
> 2. $\{f|f:\{1,2\}\to\Bbb N\}$
> 3. $\{f|f:\{1,2\}\to\Bbb N, f(1)\le f(2)\}$
> 4. $\{f|f:\Bbb N\to\{1,2\}, f(1)\le f(2)\}$

I think 1 and 4 are true. As cardinality of first option is $2^{\aleph_0}=c$ and the cardinality of the second option is $|\Bbb N^2|=\aleph_0$, the third option is a subset of the second option so it is also countable, the fourth option is a subset of the first option but I am not sure about this. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: **Hint:** Find injections $1\to 4$ and $4\to 1$, and use Cantor-Bernstein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a subset of the first, which does **not** show that it is uncountable. To show that it is uncountable you have to show that given any countable list of elements, you can construct an element not on the list. Alternatively, you can reduce the problem to a previous known result, because the condition $f(1) \le f(2)$ only restricts $f(1)$. What if we just fix/ignore $f(1)$? Then how many functions do we have? Remember that these functions are completely determined by their output on the naturals, and can thus be represented by a sequence. With the first element of the sequence fixed, the number of sequences is determined by the number of subsequences from the second onwards.

Comment: if we take f(1)=1 then f(2) can take any value, if we take f(1)=2 then f(2) can take any value except 1, in this way can we say it is same as infinite product of $\Bbb N$'s which is uncountable?

Comment: i think, I'm in wrong way

Comment: Infinite product of what? Each input gives only two choices of output. But the point is that if you fix $f(1) = 1$, then it is equivalent to ignoring what the function does on input $1$. Read my answer carefully, it tells you how to count such functions.

Comment: @Chiranjeev: No problem. By the way, if $f(n) \le f(m)$ for all natural $m,n$, then $f$ must be constant. Now what about the following: How many functions $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \{1,2\}$ are such that for any natural $m$ there is some natural $n > m$ such that $f(m) \ne f(n)$?

Comment: Ok if we take $m=1,(f(1)=1$ then rest of naturals can be send 2.
if we take $m=2,\{1,2\}\to 1$ and rest of naturals to 2. so it's like partition of naturals in two sets, also for each partition we have 2 maps. so my intuition  says there will be uncountably many functions @user21820

Comment: @Chiranjeev: No that does not answer my question. Your function must satisfy the condition that regardless of what natural $m$ I choose you can choose some natural $n>m$ such that $f(m)≠f(n)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25052/discussion-between-chiranjeev-and-user21820).

Comment: @Chiranjeev: Sorry I don't want to use the chat. You should learn how to understand first-order logic, because it is fundamental to everything else. If $f(k) = 2$ for every natural $k > 1$, then I can choose $m = 2$ and you will be unable to choose a natural $n > m$ such that $f(m) \ne f(n)$.